# regular expression in .net for validating a number

Tags: .net, regex

I need a regular expression in .net which

- will only allow a maximum of two digits after "."
- will only allow a maximum of two digits before "."
- has a maximum length of 5
- represents a number greater than 0
- represents a number not greater than 100
- has a number not greater than 11 after  ".", like 5.11, 5.10, 5.03, 5.01, 5.06, etc (not  5.12, 5.2, 5.3)

Examples:

- 1, 100, 100.00, 58, 58.10, 1.1, 0.02, .2, .02, 1.02, 11.11, 12.00, 01.09, 1.0 etc

Invalid numbers:

- 1.12, 101.12, 100.1, 100.03, 100.65, etc. and all negative values

Comment: Your specification seems inconsistent. 100 cannot be done with a maximum of 2 digits before the '.'...

Comment: How can .2 not be invalid.  .2 > .11 so surely this should be a failure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
^100\.00|\d{1,2}\.(?:11|10|0\d)$
```

OK, was simpler than I thought.

```
^100(?:\.00?)?$|^(?:\d{1,2})?(?:\.(?:1|11|10|0\d?))?$
```

This matches the new set of data.  It also matches .0 at the moment.

Comment: Not so fast. This regular expression doesn't match "100", "100.0", "1.1", "1.0"

Answer (score 1):

this regex is based on the one from Xetius:

```
^(100(?:\.00?)?|\d{1,2}(?:\.(?:11|10|0\d|0|1))?)$
```

below is the code how I Tested it:

```
class Program
{
    const string Pattern = @"^(100(?:\.00?)?|\d{1,2}(?:\.(?:11|10|0\d|0|1))?)$";
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        for (int before = 0; before < 100; before++)
        {
            Test(before.ToString());
            for (int after = 0; after < 12; after++)
            {
                Test(string.Format("{0}.{1:d2}", before, after));
                Test(string.Format("{0:d2}.{1:d2}", before, after));
                Test(string.Format(".{0:d2}", after));
            }
            Test(string.Format("{0}.{1:d}", before, 0));
            Test(string.Format("{0:d2}.{1:d}", before, 1));
        }
        // Special cases:
        Test("100");
        Test("100.0");
        Test("100.00");

        // intended to fail
        Test("00.20");
        Test("00.12");
        Test("00.00x");
        Test("000.00");
        Console.WriteLine("done.");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static void Test(string input)
    {
        Regex r = new Regex(Pattern);
        if (!r.IsMatch(input))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("no match: " + input);
        }
    }
}
```

#### Edit:

- Tweaked the regex so that 100.0 also works
- added a comment for the tests intended to fail

#### Edit2:

- Added Test for .00 - .11 and was surprised that the regex already matched them. Thanks to Xetius

Comment: so what? 0.5 is supposed to fail because you can't have a number greater than 1 as the first digit after the decimal place

Comment: The real question here is, what does 0.5 mean: 0.50 or 0.05?

Comment: When I say "failed" I mean it returned valid when it shouldn't.

Comment: 0.5 means 0.5.  0.05 is a completely different number.  That is like confusing 5 and 50

Comment: From the supplied data (Which Im sure has changed) it has to match with .01 to .11 meaning that the whole number is optional.

Answer (score 0):

`^(100(\.00?)?|\d\d?(\.(0\d|1[01]?))?)$`

Answer (score 0):

```
^(?:\d{1,2}(?:\.(?:0?\d|1[01]))?|100)$
```

Comment: 0.5 is supposed to fail. 0.5 = 0.50 > 0.11 and we can't exceed 11 after the decimal place.

Comment: When I say "failed" I meant it returned valid when it shouldn't. You placed a ? in the wrong place there.

Answer (score 0):

```
"^100(\.00?)?|\d\d?(\.(1[01]?|0\d?))?$"
```